# Open an existing view in Windows 10 Universal App in VB?

Tags: windows, vb.net, uwp

How to open a new frame window which contains an existing xaml page when I click a button from the window in universal windows app in VB?

Comment: `this.testFrame.Navigate(typeof(yourpagename));`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is Frame object in uwp Page instance. you could use [`Navigate`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/uwp/api/windows.ui.xaml.controls.frame.navigate) method to navigate to other page. For more please refer [**Implement navigation between two pages.**](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/uwp/design/basics/navigate-between-two-pages)

**VB Code**

```
Private Sub Button_Click(sender As Object, e As RoutedEventArgs)
    Frame.Navigate(GetType(TestPage))
End Sub
```